# Sorting specific values in a dataframe column based on another column in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to write a python code to summarize a number of f1 statistic csv files. Currently what I'm trying to summarize is the top 20 f1 drivers with the most wins as well as the top 10 nations with the most f1 wins. I'm using pandas data frames to aggregate the data. the two csv files I'm working with has columns is driverRef(the name of the driver) and positionOrder (the finishing position of the driver up to position 39) I want to look at only first place finished

```
import sys
import csv
import pandas as pd

driv_df = pd.read_csv('drivers.csv', sep=',')
# print(driv_df)

resu_df = pd.read_csv('results.csv', sep=',')
# print(resu_df)


# merging the drivers.csv and results.csv files based on the driverId
merge1_df = pd.merge(resu_df,driv_df, left_on=['driverId'],right_on=['driverId'],how='inner')
merge1_df.to_csv('output1.csv')

# counting the first place position
driver_rankdf = merge1_df.groupby(['positionOrder']).size()
print(driver_rankdf)

# counting first place position based on driverRef
driver_rankdf = merge1_df.groupby(['positionOrder', 'driverRef']).size().sort_values(ascending=False) \
  .reset_index(name='Driver Wins Rank')
print(driver_rankdf)

#adding the driver's nationality to ranked df
driv_nation = driv_df['nationality']
driver_rankdf = driver_rankdf.join(driv_nation)

driver_rankdf = merge1_df.groupby(['positionOrder', 'driverRef', 'nationality']).size().sort_values(ascending=False) \
  .reset_index(name='Driver Wins Rank')
print(driver_rankdf)


# creating new csv for ranked data
driver_rankdf.to_csv('driver_rank.csv')
```

I'm looking to count only the 'positionOrder' values that have 1 as the value. However, when I run the program, the output csv file is counting all values of 'positionOrder' and ranking them (so hamilton 2nd place count is ranked as 5th).

|  | positionOrder | driverRef | nationality | DriverWinsRank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | hamilton | British | 103 |
| 1 | 1 | michael_schumacher | British | 91 |
| 2 | 1 | vettel | German | 53 |
| 3 | 1 | prost | German | 51 |
| 4 | 2 | hamilton | Britsh | 48 |

How can I just rank/count the values '1' for positionOrder?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Could you please [edit] to include an example of your expected output, since it's different from your current output as provided?

Comment: basically all I want to count is when positionOrder = 1

Answer (score 0):

You didn't select only the records where positionOrder == 1. The code may be:

```
driver_1strank = merge1_df.query('positionOrder' == 1)

driver_rankdf = driver_1strank.groupby(['positionOrder',  'driverRef']).size().sort_values(ascending=False) \
  .reset_index(name='Driver Wins Rank')
```

Comment: ok that makes sense, where would i put that in the code?